# PHPBrew: cannot install or add argon2i hashing

Tags: php, php-7.2, phpbrew

I didn't find a way to add argon2i hashing to a running 7.2.27 version in phpbrew. Is there a way to get it done?
I tried

```
phpbrew ext install argon2i
```

I get

```
Downloading https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/argon2i/stable.txt via curl extension
CurlKit\CurlException: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found at [https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/argon2i/stable.txt:The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found]
Trace:

    0) CurlKit\CurlDownloader->request('https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/argon2i/stable.txt')
    1) PhpBrew\Downloader\PhpCurlDownloader->process('https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/argon2i/stable.txt', '/tmp/phpbrew_R5kDEJ')
    2) PhpBrew\Downloader\BaseDownloader->download('https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/argon2i/stable.txt')
    3) PhpBrew\Downloader\BaseDownloader->request('https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/argon2i/stable.txt')
    4) PhpBrew\Extension\Provider\PeclProvider->buildPackageDownloadUrl('stable')
    5) PhpBrew\Extension\ExtensionDownloader->download(PhpBrew\Extension\Provider\PeclProvider, 'stable')
    6) PhpBrew\Command\ExtensionCommand\InstallCommand->execute('argon2i')
    7) call_user_func_array([PhpBrew\Command\ExtensionCommand\InstallCommand, 'execute'], ['argon2i'])
    8) CLIFramework\CommandBase->executeWrapper(['argon2i'])
    9) CLIFramework\Application->run(['/usr/local/bin/phpbrew', 'ext', 'install', 'argon2i'])
    10) PhpBrew\Console->runWithTry(['/usr/local/bin/phpbrew', 'ext', 'install', 'argon2i'])
    11) require('phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/bin/phpbrew')
```

So there is no ext argon2 or argon2i.

I surely installed argon2 via apt-get

```
sudo apt install argon2 libargon2-0 libargon2-0-dev
```

successfully.

But I don't know how I get PHP to use that library. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Found it: you have to reinstall with option --with-password-argon2:

```
phpbrew install php-7.3.19 +default -- --with-password-argon2
```